# Creating Dependent dropdown based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have come across a requirement where I need to create dependent dropdown based on cell value.

For Example:

If my value in a cell is ZRDDCAM01 then corresponding to this value I want 9 values as dropdown:-

> ZRDDCAM011 to ZRDDCAM019 ie number 1 to 9 appended to ZRDDCAM01 value as a dropdown.

Similarly If my value is ZRDDCAM02 then corresponding to this I want 9 values as dropdown:-

> ZRDDCAM021 to ZRDDCAM029 ie number 1 to 9 appended to ZRDDCAM02 value as a dropdown list.

Similary If I have any other value in a cell I want a dropdown list with 1 to 9 appended to that cell value.

Can you please tell how I can achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple search for this topic will get you a lot of tutorials.

Comment: A dropdown can be based on a range.  And the range can display the value of a formula.  So if A1 is a cell with Data Validation pointing to a list with a range containing a formula like `=IF(ISBLANK($A$1)," ",$A$1&ROW())` then the list will have the dependant values you require.  For a start look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I know how to create a  dependent dropdown list but in my case I want a formula which returns a list containing 1-9 values appended to the cell value.Like teylyn done below with sequence operation,I tried with TEXTJOIN operation but I dont have 365 subscription.How to achieve the solution if we dont have 365 solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 365 subscription of Excel, you can use the Sequence() function to dynamically generate the values for the dropdown list. This list does not have to be in the same sheet, of course.

The formula in cell B1 of the screenshot is

`=A1&SEQUENCE(9)`

It has NOT been copied down. It automatically spills down.

[image]

The definition of the data validation is with a List, using

`=$B$1#`

[image]

Comment: TEXTJOIN() is another function that can be used to achieve the same by providing the list that we get using TEXTJOIN() function in Data validation column but that also requires office 365 subscription.Is their any way we can do it without 365 subscription?@teylyn

Comment: I have found an alternative solution using VBA and it works for all with and without 365 subscription using VBA